# Vista issue with shift key

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keymap

When I press the shift key on my laptop keyboard, it is mapped to 'ctrl+v' which does a paste. I thought it was the keyboard but then I replaced it with a wireless one, it still gives me the same issue.

I can't just turn off the shift key altogether because I do need it at times.

Compaq model 8510w; Vista operating system

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you enabled input assistance tools like sticky keys? Go to system settings, then keyboard, and try disabling some or all of them. While you are there, check if you enabled layout switching and the right keyboard layout is still enabled.